# Fissile equivalent for fusion

Tags: adjectives

If an isotope(such as uranium 235) can support fission, one might say it is fissile. What would you call a material like deuterium can support fusion, what would you call it?

Comment: Why not *fusile*? It is properly formed.

Answer (score 3):

U-235 and Pu-239 are fissile, or fissionable, as are other isotopes (e.g., U-233, Pu-241).  D and T are ***fusionable***.  I don't think fusionable is used very much, but see Patents, Fusionable Material Target, http://www.google.com/patents/US20060198487.  "Can support fission" or "can support fusion" is a strange wording.  Better to say "can undergo nuclear fission" or "can undergo nuclear fusion."  I could go on, but I won't.

Upon reflection, "can support nuclear fission" is OK for U-235 and Pu-239. Wilipedia defines fissile as "In nuclear engineering, fissile material is material capable of sustaining a nuclear fission chain reaction. By definition, fissile material can sustain a chain reaction with neutrons of any energy."
Of course, a lot of engineering goes into the sustaining or supporting part, but it has been achieved.  As for fusion, we don't have fusion reactors yet.

Comment: For such an arcane technical question, we'd need someone from the field to tell us what they actually not.  Not sort of "nice interesting thoughts on it" as you and I have offered here, ab  :)

Comment: @Joe Blow It's not as arcane as some of the English language questions!  But it is more nuclear engineering than physics.  It's not fusible and fusionable -- both are OK --  it is the exact  implications of "support".

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it

> fusible

?

Realistically, just ask on the physics site.  Highly technical questions are not really for this site.

BTW I'm not entirely sure if "fissile" literally is used to mean "can support fission".

Comment: fusible is fine...as good as and maybe better than fusionable.  There are also patents on fusible..."Neutron generator using compressed fusible material and laser pulse 
US 20100290574 A1"

Comment: *Fusible* normally means [able to be fused by heat/melting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fusible). The issue is that fissile is defined by what's practical in a nuclear reactor, rather than meaning what can be fissioned in theory. When people start routinely fusing nuclei, we may find fusible is more common with that sense.